# mod_rewrite HTTPS and Single Point of Entry

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been fighting mod_rewrite for a while now - I cannot make it work so it does a "if the file doesn't exist, redirect to index.php"-redirection, as used by most single-point-of-entry frameworks such as Slim, CI, Symfony2, while also redirecting any HTTP requests to HTTPS.

It looks like this, which works, but allows HTTP:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Which gave me a redirect loop.

What's the correct way to do this with mod_rewrite? I want it to first redirect HTTP to HTTPS, then on the following request redirect everything that doesn't exist to index.php, but serve anything that does.

I cannot use the Redirect Virtual Host directive, as the servers are behind a load balancer and only listen on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the key was in the "behind a load balancer".

Because http is always off, the last of the configurations I posted, which was the "correct one", caused a loop.

I changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

And everything worked.